# How to open, convert 3DMF files?

Tags: quicktime, macos

3DMF is a Mac-Classic-era QuickTime data format for describing 3D objects. However, QuickTime 3D was not supported in OS X, so neither QuickTime X, nor QuickTime 7, open them.

I do have OS9 in SheepShaver, but that crashes every time I try to open one.

I have been unable to find an application that can open them and convert them to something more relevant.

This website has a collection of models of famous buildings in this format. *(The site is firmly stuck in the mid-90s, providing software for 'Power Macintosh' :lol:)*

http://www.greatbuildings.com/types/models/models.html

... and I've been trying for some years to find something that can open them.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: FWIW I was able to open up some 3DMF files from the link using DesignWorkshop Lite in a Windows XP virtual machine. Could only export as a 2D image file though.

Comment: not sure wether this works: you can try  [conversion.ai](https://conversionai.com/file/image/3dmf-quick-draw-3-d-meta-file/blend-blender-3-d-data-file) to convert your files to blender (or any other of the supported formats).